# how to convert decimal into bcd without using any library

Tags: c++

```
string decimal_to_bcd(int num)
{
   if (num == 0) {
        cout << "0000";
        return 0;
    }

    // To store the reverse of n
    int rev = 0;

    // Reversing the digits
    while (num > 0) {
        rev = rev * 10 + (num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
    // Iterate through all digits in rev
    while (rev > 0) {

        // Find Binary for each digit
        // using bit set
        bitset<4> b(rev % 10);

        // Print the Binary conversion
        // for current digit
        
        cout << b << ' ';

        // Divide rev by 10 for next digit
        rev /= 10;
}
}
```

i have wrote this but problem is that i dont want to use any library like bitset i have used . can you help me how it can be done without library

Comment: Is that second loop supposed to show the bits in each digit? If so, you already know how to do that. You've done it in base 10 in the first loop. Now do the same thing in base 2.

Comment: i didnot understand you. can you please do that for me

Comment: Why don't you use some `char buf[16];`, and why don't you study -at least for inspiration- the source code of *existing* open source libraries (like [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)....) already having some source code doing what you want? Be sure to mention your findings to your teacher!

Answer (score 1):

You can try by this method.

```
auto dec_to_bin(int n)
{
    std::vector<std::bitset<4>> repr;
    while(n > 0){
        repr.push_back(std::bitset<4>(n % 10));
        n /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(repr.begin(), repr.end());
    return repr;
}


int main()
{
    for(auto b : dec_to_bin(215)){
        std::cout << b << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to convert decimal to BCD not binary

Comment: Oh sorry about that just updated the code!